# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Google_Service_Gmail_Resource_Users' not found even after calling autoload.php?

Tags: php, google-api, google-oauth, gmail-api

I'm getting this error (I'm using PHP 7.0 and Google PHP API 2.9.1, and I'm using OAuth credentials for Web application):

```
Uncaught Error: Class 'Google_Service_Gmail_Resource_Users' not found in /google-api-2.9.1/vendor/google/apiclient-services/src/Google/Service/Gmail.php:106
Stack trace:
#0 /public_html/oauth2callback.php(20): Google_Service_Gmail->__construct(Object(Google\Client))
#1 {main} thrown in /public_html/googe-api-2.9.1/vendor/google/apiclient-services/src/Google/Service/Gmail.php on line 106
```

And here is what Im trying to do:

### My index.php:

```
<?php    
include_once __DIR__ . '/google-api-2.9.1/vendor/autoload.php';
    

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig(__DIR__ . 'credenciales.json');
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Gmail::GMAIL_READONLY);


if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
  $gmail = new Google_Service_Gmail($client);

  $user = 'me';
  $list = $gmail->users_messages->listUsersMessages($user, [ 'q' => ['from:someEmail@gmail.com in:inbox'], ]);
  
  $messageList = $list->getMessages();
  $inboxMessage = [];
  
  foreach($messageList as $mlist){
  
      $optParamsGet2['format'] = 'full';
      $single_message = $gmail->users_messages->get('me',$mlist->id, $optParamsGet2);
  
      $message_id = $mlist->id;
      $headers = $single_message->getPayload()->getHeaders();
      $snippet = $single_message->getSnippet();
  
      foreach($headers as $single) {
  
          if ($single->getName() == 'Subject') {
  
              $message_subject = $single->getValue();
  
          }
  
          else if ($single->getName() == 'Date') {
  
              $message_date = $single->getValue();
              $message_date = date('M jS Y h:i A', strtotime($message_date));
          }
  
          else if ($single->getName() == 'From') {
  
              $message_sender = $single->getValue();
              $message_sender = str_replace('"', '', $message_sender);
          }
      }
  
  
       $inboxMessage[] = [
          'messageId' => $message_id,
          'messageSnippet' => $snippet,
          'messageSubject' => $message_subject,
          'messageDate' => $message_date,
          'messageSender' => $message_sender
      ];
  
      echo json_encode($inboxMessage);
  
  }  



} else {
  $redirect_uri = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/oauth2callback.php';
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}
```

### My oauth2callback.php file:

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/google-api-2.9.1/vendor/autoload.php';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig(__DIR__ . 'credenciales.json');
$client->setRedirectUri('https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/oauth2callback.php');
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Gmail::GMAIL_READONLY);


if (! isset($_GET['code'])) {
  $auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($auth_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
} else {
  $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
  $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();

  $gmail = new Google_Service_Gmail($client);

  $user = 'me';
  $list = $gmail->users_messages->listUsersMessages($user, [ 'q' => ['from:someEmail@gmail.com in:inbox'], ]);
  
  $messageList = $list->getMessages();
  $inboxMessage = [];
  
  foreach($messageList as $mlist){
  
      $optParamsGet2['format'] = 'full';
      $single_message = $gmail->users_messages->get('me',$mlist->id, $optParamsGet2);
  
      $message_id = $mlist->id;
      $headers = $single_message->getPayload()->getHeaders();
      $snippet = $single_message->getSnippet();
  
      foreach($headers as $single) {
  
          if ($single->getName() == 'Subject') {
  
              $message_subject = $single->getValue();
  
          }
  
          else if ($single->getName() == 'Date') {
  
              $message_date = $single->getValue();
              $message_date = date('M jS Y h:i A', strtotime($message_date));
          }
  
          else if ($single->getName() == 'From') {
  
              $message_sender = $single->getValue();
              $message_sender = str_replace('"', '', $message_sender);
          }
      }
  
  
       $inboxMessage[] = [
          'messageId' => $message_id,
          'messageSnippet' => $snippet,
          'messageSubject' => $message_subject,
          'messageDate' => $message_date,
          'messageSender' => $message_sender
      ];
  
      echo json_encode($inboxMessage);
  
  }  

}
```

### When I accept the app, google takes me to:

> https://mywebsite.com/oauth2callback.php?code=4/8521e-kahsd875CLzcbtvppohs584ehtptRa6nXZpjhbFTDGFQjN9jgvQj_7be2E2j654ytv&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly

**So, I go get pass the authorization screen from Google, I accept my app, and then a blank screen. The error shown comes from the error log file.**

Why I get that Class 'Google_Service_Gmail_Resource_Users' is not found when I do call the autoload file?

Comment: Where did `/librerias/google-api-2.9.1/vendor/autoload.php` come from? Assuming it's put there by Composer, you should be running that from the root of your project, not the library's folder.

Comment: Also your library files should never be under your publicly accessible files. This means a simple misconfiguration of your web server opens sensitive data like your app configuration to the public.

Comment: So `cd /var/www/html/myapp/ && composer require google/apiclient`. Then in your PHP `require_once("/var/www/html/myapp/vendor/autoload.php");` and THEN configure your web server to use `/var/www/html/myapp/public` as a document root and put your public facing files in there. Remove the `librerias` directory.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I didn't use composer, it's just a demo server and I'm just trying to make this work. But you suggestions are quite good, so I started again, this time, didn't use any librerias folder. I updated the question accordingly.

Comment: Ok I didn't see a vendor folder in the github repo so figured you'd added it after. I'd say using composer would make things easier for you regardless. It looks like the downloaded version includes a preinstalled Composer vendor directory.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the problem. Downloaded the library, created foo.php with this content: `require_once("google-api-php-client--PHP8.0/vendor/autoload.php"); new Google_Service_Gmail_Resource_Users();` and did not get a class not found error.

Comment: Maybe because it's a different version? I don't think I can use that with PHP7.0... :'(

Comment: That's the version I use. I assume the result would be the same for an older version. (I hope you mean PHP 7.4, not 7.0!)

Comment: Do you have a file called `google-api-2.9.1/vendor/google/apiclient-services/src/Google/Service/Gmail/Resource/Users.php`?

Comment: @miken32 Big thanks! That folder has NOT been copied properly! It's working as expected now, again, many thanks! Please post the answer so I can approve it.
By the way, I do have PHP 7.4 (because of phpMailer that is still in use in the project).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I see a few problems with your current setup. The one relating to your problem is that you aren't using Composer. It's small and simple and easy to use, and handles all the autoloading stuff for you. No worries about missing directories or unzipping errors. The [download version](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/releases) of the Google API client already includes a pre-built Composer vendor folder, so you aren't saving any disk space or code complexity by skipping it.

Second is your directory structure; the way your server is set up, it's trivial for someone to access https://mywebsite.example.com/credenciales.json and get your private data.

So here's what I recommend:

- In your document root (`/var/www/html/home_dir`) create a `public` folder and copy `index.php` and `oauth2callback.php` to that folder.
- Update your server configuration to point to `/var/www/html/home_dir/public` as your document root
- Change into `/var/www/html/home_dir` and run `composer require google/apiclient` ([install Composer](https://getcomposer.org/download/) if you haven't already)
- Edit your PHP files as needed, adjusting the path to `credentiales.json` and changing your `require` directives to point to `/var/www/html/home_dir/vendor/autoload.php`.